# Cómo ignorar filas en blanco en archivo CSV a la hora de usar el plugin leaflet omnivore

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

Estoy usando el plugin de lesflet omnívore para con archivos CSV, pero omnívore devuelve un error de análisis porque los archivos tienen las primeras 6 filas vacías. ¿Hay alguna manera de decirle a este complemento que ignore las primeras líneas de un CSV?

Recibo estos archivos de una fuente externa de terceros y no puedo modificarlos en su fuente.

Mi código:

```
runLayer = omnivore.csv(urlCSV, opcionescsv)
.on('ready', function () {
    if (mapaConCoordenadas===false){
        map.fitBounds(runLayer.getBounds());
    }

    markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
        removeOutsideVisibleBounds: true,
        maxClusterRadius: 50
    });
    markers.addLayer(runLayer);
    map.addLayer(markers);

    var contador = 0;
    runLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        contador++;

        layer.on('click', function (e) {
            latDestino = e.latlng.lat;
            lonDestino = e.latlng.lng;
            if (circulo != null) {
                circulo.disablePermanentHighlight();
            }
            circulo = this;
            this.enablePermanentHighlight();
        });

        layer.on("popupopen", function (e) {
            var x = document.querySelector('.leaflet-popup-content a[href^="http"]');
            x.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                window.open(x.getAttribute('href'), '_system');
            }, false);
        });
```

Comment: No se como funciona omnivore pero yo con un csv que tenia añadi `if(celda != "")` y ya, no se donde sacas el dato exactamente pero con una condicion puedes saltar los elementos vacios

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, mi problema es que omnívore parsea el archivo por su cuenta, y también lo descarga, por lo que me tocaría modificar el código fuente del plugin